# Adding tests to an Test Execution using Jira API for Cloud

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to call some HTTP Requests to the Cloud Jira, in order to add some Tests to a Test Execution Ticket, eventually to also change the test result to FAIL or PASS after its running.
My issue is that I cannot find any HTTP request for this, except https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Test+Executions+-+REST which does not work. I assume it is because this is for Server Jira, not Cloud.

Is there any other way to do these requests?

What I want to do is publish the test results after each test is done running, not after the whole suite has run, using these requests. Any other solution than the one I presented would be great.